# Running cmd command from java using process builder

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, processbuilder

I am trying to convert an HTML file to pdf and view it using my pdf viewer(vsmartpdf.exe).Its a cmd command which goes like "vmartpdf.exe -c 'path of html file' 'path of output folder' ". I am trying to execute this command using java program . Below is what i did.

```
 import java.io.IOException;


public class LoadTesting implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //String command = "C:\\Users\\vishalt\\Desktop\\New Source\\deliver\\vsmartpdf\\vsmartpdf.exe";
            //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c "+command);
            //Process process = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\Users\\vishalt\\Vsmartfinal\" && dir").start();
             Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
             String[] cmd = { "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Vsmartfinal\\vsmartpdf.exe", "-c", "C:\\Users\\vishalt\\Desktop\\output\\SCB_MOLPU.HTML", " C:\\Users\\vishalt\\Desktop\\output\\"};
             Process p = rt.exec(cmd);
            System.out.println("Called");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

then i am calling this thread . But i am getting error as 
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.
Can somebody please help me with it

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that `C:\Users\Desktop\Vsmartfinal\vsmartpdf.exe` doesn't exist at the time when the code is executed.

A common source for this problem is that this executable exists in a developer machine but not on the production server.